# How can we store values example : "language" = "english" in local database in xamarin.ios

Tags: ios, database, xamarin, storage

just need to know how can i store some keys values data like language as a key and english as a value in xamarin ios, and how to get them any place in the app.
i know in angular2 and ionic we use localstorage but here what's the alternative of local storage

Answer (score 1):

use [NSUserDefaults](https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/ios/application_fundamentals/user-defaults/)

```
// Get Shared User Defaults
var plist = NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults;

// Get value
var lang = plist.StringForKey("language");

// write value
plist.SetString("key","value");
```

Comment: i used this instead : set : NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.SetValueForKey(newValue, newKey);
get :  NSString value = (NSString)NSUserDefaults.StandardUserDefaults.ValueForKey(newKey);